# Unable to Install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore in ASP.NET Core Project

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.1

Never had a problem doing this before, but today, when I run the command `Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`, the following error ensures:

```
NU1107: Version conflict detected for Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions. Install/reference Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions 2.2.1 directly to 
project WebApplication1 to resolve this issue. 
 WebApplication1 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.2.1 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions (>= 2.2.1) 
 WebApplication1 -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.1 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions (>= 2.1.1 && < 2.2.0).
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'WebApplication1'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

Really not quite sure how to resolve it.

I attempted to install a previous version to no avail: `Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore -Version 2.1.0`

Comment: I see your project already have `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` meta package than why do you need to install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` separately as your `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` already containing the required version of  `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`.

Comment: @TanvirArjel The problem is, I get the exact same message if I add a dependency to a class library (.net core) which has my DbConbtext in it. All my models and DbContext are in that library.

Comment: Okay! Best option is add `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App"/>` this into your class library `.csproj`

Comment: @TanvirArjel Interesting suggestion. But it did not work. I got a yellow triangle in the dependancies node in Solution Explorer. In any case, I want to use migrations and other features of EF.

Comment: There is some problem in your other dependencies too.

Comment: In order to use EF Core 2.2, you need to update the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` package to [v2.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App)

Comment: @IvanStoev That kinda got me there. The big problem was that I had not installed the .NET Core 2.2 SDK. It never used to be this hard. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I just installed EFCore 2.1.11. It seems that EFCore and AspNetCore go side by side in versions.

Answer (score 0):

Version of EntitiyFrameworkCore and ASP.Net should be the same